# Iterate an array and check objects with filter and skip the null values

Tags: javascript

So I'm iterating an array with objects and checking for a specific id, and this works fine when It has an id, but some time that is null and when it is it throws an error can't read properties of null or something similar.

Here is my function, and I would like to check the case, if it is null then just skip and don't iterate that object so I can avoid that error:

Here is the function:

```js
const d = vehicles.vehicles.filter((vehicle) => vehicle.owner._id === quick.temp.customer._id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a simple check if variable is an object:

```
const d = vehicles.vehicles.filter((vehicle) => vehicle && vehicle.owner && vehicle.owner._id === quick.temp.customer._id);
```

This might fail if `vehicle.owner` is anything non-null and not an object, but you can further expand it to check the type `vehicle.owner instanceof Object`

With ES6 you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining): `?`

```
const d = vehicles.vehicles.filter((vehicle) => vehicle?.owner?._id === quick.temp.customer._id);
```

It's a little slower though.

And finally you can wrap the condition into `try{}catch(e){}` than you don't have to worry about errors:

```
const d = vehicles.vehicles.filter((vehicle) =>
{
  try
  {
    return vehicle.owner._id === quick.temp.customer._id
  }
  catch(er){}
});
```

This method is the slowest of them all
https://jsbench.me/zzl1871t5u/1

Comment: And how can you do that, I mean to check the owner one because its the same I think